# HTMLElement focus() method Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript

I have come across an issue which i feel is rather odd though I'm still learning javascript. I want to do some calculations only when a value for a state is set, if the state isn't set then I want the form field focused.

Now the issue is that the code below doesn't work

```
document.getElementById('cart-hplus').addEventListener('submit', estimateTotal);

function estimateTotal(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var state = document.getElementById('s-state').value;
    if (state === '') {
        alert("Please choose your preferred shipping state.");

        state.focus();
    }
}
```

> Uncaught TypeError: state.focus is not a function

But this works but i don't think it's good habit declaring a variable then using the document object again inside my if statement

```
function estimateTotal(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var state = document.getElementById('s-state').value;
    if (state === '') {
        alert("Please choose your preferred shipping state.");

        document.getElementById('s-state').focus();
    }
}
```

What is wrong with the first code?

Comment: `state` is String as you get `.value` on the element. Remove `.value` and use `state.value` in the `if` condition.

Comment: Store reference of element in a  variable `var state = document.getElementById('s-state');` then use `state.value` and `state.focus() `

Comment: Thanks guys, I see where the mistake was coming from. I understand it better now. @Satpal nice explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not making a distinction between the state input control and the state value. You are going to need to use 2 variables:

```
function estimateTotal(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var state = document.getElementById('s-state');
    var stateValue = state.value;
    if (stateValue === '') {
        alert("Please choose your preferred shipping state.");
        state.focus();
    }
}
```

Also, the way you have it is fine. There is nothing wrong with referencing the object twice.

Comment: Appreciate the lesson, I have made correction to my code and it's working now.

Comment: Great! Good to hear.

Answer (score 2):

In your first code make following change,

```
document.getElementById('cart-hplus').addEventListener('submit', estimateTotal);

function estimateTotal(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var state = document.getElementById('s-state');
    if (state.value === '') {
        alert("Please choose your preferred shipping state.");

        state.focus();
    }
}
```